# Can MutationObserver listen to changing DOM element order?

Tags: javascript

I want to listen to the change of DOM element order.  For example, I want to listen to the change of Item 1 swapping with Item 2.

Before:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

After:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Can this be done with MutationObserver?  It seems like MutationObserver can only listen to add or remove of DOM elements.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Anything can be done - but What have you tried to achieve this ? Stack-over flow is not a free coding service you need to provide us your minimum efforts to achieve this or if you are stuck at something so some one can help with your code! Also consider doing your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your work. Read here how to ask a [Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's an observer, but the callback has access to a `mutationList` that you loop over. Usually, since you know what made the change in the first place if you wrote the code, it's not necessary to use a `MutationObserver` since you know what's happening when an Event occurred in the first place.

Comment: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-mutationobserver - “Instructs the user agent to observe a given target (a node) and report any mutations based on the criteria given by options (an object).” The parent is modified if the children are re-arranged.